# F# discriminated unions of user defined types; respecting custom attributes

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I am trying to use a discriminated union to represent some user-defined types; however, the types that make up the DU cases contain custom attributes that are not being respected by the DU. For example, I am marshaling a file header that contains some optional fields in a header extension, depending on the program that wrote the file. The fields of the struct also have a custom attribute that allows the fields of the struct to be marshaled with the correct endianness, given by `[<endian>]`. Given a generic basic header struct,

```
[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)>]
type generic_header = {
    [<endian>] header_size: int16
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 55)>]
    file_version: string
    [<endian>] file_size: int16
    header_extension: bool
    }
```

and a header extension with +/- fields depending on the program by which the header was generated,

```
[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)>]
    type header_extension = {
    [<endian>] extended_field_1: int16
    [<endian>] extended_field_2: float32
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)>]
    extended_array: byte[]
    [<endian>] extended_field_3: int16
    ...
    }
```

is it possible to have a discriminated union (or even another struct) that can hold these types, and the DU type be used to marshal the stream into the contained structures? If I marshal each type individually, then the endian attribute is respected and I get the right data.

What I have tried so far is:

```
[<Struct>]
type file_header =
    | Header of Header: generic_header
    | Extension of Extension: header_extension
```

or:

```
[<Struct>] type file_header = | Header of generic_header * header_extension
```

or some case logic to do one of the following based on the value of the first field of generic_header:

```
[<Struct>] type file_header_from_prog_1 = | Header of generic_header * prog_1_header_extension
[<Struct>] type file_header_from_prog_2 = | Header of generic_header * prog_2_header_extension
[<Struct>] type file_header_from_prog_3 = | Header of generic_header * prog_3_header_extension
```

However, when I use the file_header type for marshaling, it correctly marshals the right number of bytes into the structure, but it does so without respecting the endian tag on the fields.

My goal is to construct a "super-type" that contains all of the possible extensions and types that could make up the file header I am marshaling, so that I don't have to marshal each type individually. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered not using an attribute for this? One thing that make work nicely is a single case DU for 'endian' Something a kin to `type endian = endian of int16`